# Why is $\frac{n-1}{n}$ always in its simplest form?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

So I was just messing around on my calculator and I noticed that for every positive integer the formula $\frac{n-1}{n}$ is always a fraction in its simplest form im not quite sure why this happens is there a case where this is not true?

Comment: Any common factor of $n$ and $n-1$ divides $1$.

Comment: When $n=1$ you get a potential exception.

Comment: @mark Bennet Its still in its simplest form though

Comment: I don't think $\frac 01$ would be considered by most people the simplest form for $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $n-(n-1)=1$ and this means that $n$ and $n-1$ are co-prime. Can you see why ?

Any common divisor to $n$ and $n-1$ divides their difference...

Comment: @marawalix is there some kind of law related to this?

Answer (score 3):

Using Bezout's Lemma, we know that $\text{gcd}(n,n-1)=1$ because $n-(n-1)=1$. This means they have no common prime factors, so you can't find any natural number $k\neq 1$ such that $k\mid n$ and $k\mid(n-1)$, hence the fraction $\frac{n-1}{n}$ is always in its simplest form.